# How to simulate bash process substitution with node.js?

Tags: node.js, process, pipe

Assuming that I have `1.js`:

```
process.stdout.write("Hello world.\n")
```

And `2.js`:

```
process.stdout.write(
    require("fs")
    .readFileSync(process.argv[2])
    .toString()
    .replace(/Hello/,"Goodbye")
)
```

and can execute the following command within bash terminal to get `2.js` output:

```
$ node 2.js <(node 1.js)
Goodbye world.
```

how can I simulate the same mechanism of process substitution without `bash` mediation? What should I write in `3.js`?

```
var child_process = require("child_process")
var cp1 = child_process.spawn("node",[__dirname + "/1.js"])
var dev_fd_pipe = ??? // How do I create it?
var cp2 = child_process.spawn("node",[__dirname + "/2.js",dev_fd_pipe])
cp2.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

Comment: Yes, `process.argv[2]` must be a file name and the file must be an unnamed pipe that located in `/dev/fd` and shared between `1.js`, `2.js` and `3.js`. I need an equivalent of `int pipe(int fd[2])` from `unistd.h`. http://www.cs.uml.edu/~fredm/courses/91.308/files/pipes.html

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Comment: I search about that but I think there is no pipe in nodejs because there is no global solution that woks in every operating system. I think you can create file your self and delete it at the end, but it takes time. if your operating system is Linux i can write a nodejs addon that uses linux pipe natively and provide nodejs api for you.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right and there is no native node.js solution. Yes, my OS is Linux and it would be awesome if you will create an addon for this. Thank you for help.

Comment: Ok, I will write it and put its link here :)

Comment: You need something like [this](https://github.com/1995parham/Loole/blob/master/test/test.js) ? I push the module in npm then provide sample here.

Comment: Sorry to say but no. In your example you create a named pipe that has a path `/tmp/Hello` but I need an unnamed pipe that appears only in `/dev/fd/` for the process that creates the pipe and it’s descendants.

Comment: Ok, I will create unnamed version too.

Comment: checkout my improved example with pipe please.

Comment: Created an issue on github.